# Failed to create any Java EE Project eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have problem with my eclipse juno i couldn't create any java EE project evry time i create one project i get an error said:

the selected wizard couldn't be started reason

Plug-in "org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.jca.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.jca.ui.internal.wizard.ConnectorProjectWizard".
Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.project.facet.IJ2EEFacetConstants

and the class that couldn't be started depend on project kind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like something got corrupted in your eclipse installation.

The best advise I can give you is download a fresh copy of it